# CodeDom Public Events between Platform and compiled strategy

Tags: c#, codedom

Having a bit of an issue and I can't seem to think of a proper way to do this.

Situation:

I'm writing a simple platform that will take in a "WhateverStrategy.cs" file and compile it under my platform using CodeDom.

My platform has a few public events. For example:

Level1Update.

I'd like to be able to have the new strategy I'm compiling (the WhateverStrategy.cs) to have access to the Event that is part of my platform?

So I can have multiple strategies running using the 1 Level1Update event.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What exactly is your "platform"? Is it a DLL? Have you tried adding a reference to it when compiling the strategy?

Comment: @svick - My platform is a Windows Form application.  The goal is to Have the application run (platform) and load up individual strategies.  Then have that strategy receive events from my platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the events are public, you can set the application as a reference (by adding it to [`CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.referencedassemblies)). That way, the file you're compiling will be able to use them, just like events from any other library (there is almost no difference between libraries and applications in .Net).